# Create mutations in GraphQL with a lot of use cases

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I'm a newbie in GraphQL and need some advice (best practice) in creating mutations in GraphQL (particular with `graphene-python`). Let's suppose we have some `Task` and a `User`. Now I want to create `Task` mutation, that covers three cases:

1. Create `Task`.
2. Create `Task` and assign existing `User` to this `Task`.
3. Create `Task` and assign newly created `User` to this `Task`.

So, is this a good idea to implement this as a single QraphQL "entry point", or it's better to create another mutation for the third case (maybe)?

```
      mutation {
       createTask(taskTitle: "Do some stuff"){
        task {
         id
        }
       }
      }

      mutation {
       createTask(taskTitle: "Do some stuff",
                  user: {id: "ggdf00askladnl42"}){
        task {
         id
        }
       }
      }

      mutation {
       createTask(taskTitle: "Do some stuff",
                  user: {email: "j.doe@example.com", fullName: "John Doe"}){
        task {
         id
        }
       }
      }
```

and respective mutation in `graphene-python`:

```
class CreateTODO(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        task_title = graphene.NonNull(graphene.String)
        user = UserInput()

    task = graphene.Field(lambda: Task)

    def mutate(self, info, task_title, user=None):
        #
        #  Do some stuff here
        #
        return CreateTODO(task=task)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 3., if it turns out that you're going to need a `createUser` mutation anyway, then it's going to be a *simpler* implementation to start out with two separate mutations:

1. `createUser`
2. `createTask` (using the user returned from `createUser`

You won't be able to combine these two mutations into a single HTTP request though.