# mutation when having multiple foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, graphene-python

I am learning graphql and graphene-django today. I could query and mutate the simple table but could not mutate when the table has foreign key relationship. I have a model like this

```
class Company(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)


class Brand(models.Model):

    ZERO = 'Zero'
    ZEROTOTEN = 'ZTT'
    TENTOTWENTY = 'TTT'

    NUMBER_OF_FRANCHISES = (
        (ZERO, '0'),
        (ZEROTOTEN, '0 - 10'),
        (TENTOTWENTY, '10 - 20'),
    )

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    franchising_date = models.DateTimeField()
    number_of_franchises = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=NUMBER_OF_FRANCHISES, default=None)

class BusinessModel(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company_business_model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, related_name='industry', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    segments = models.ForeignKey(Segment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    total_investment = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TOTAL_INVESTMENT, default=None)
    franchise_fee = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FRANCHISE_FEE, default=None)
```

With such kind of model, I have my following schema with input type but no idea on how can i create a table for brand and business model also as they are linked with company.

```
class CompanyInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

        name = graphene.String(description='Name of your company')
        email = graphene.String(description='Email of your company')
        phone_number = graphene.String(description='Phone number of your company')
        director = graphene.String(description='Director of your company')
        franchise_head = graphene.String(description='Franchise Head of your company')


class BrandInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

    company = graphene.List(CompanyInput)
    name = graphene.String()
    franchising_date = graphene.String()
    number_of_franchises = graphene.String()


class BusinessModelInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

    company = graphene.List(CompanyInput)
    industry = graphene.List(IndustryInput)
    segments = graphene.String(SegmentInput)
    total_investment = graphene.String()
    franchise_fee = graphene.String()


# only a table for company can be created with this way but I have no idea on how can i create brand and business model table either as they are 
# linked to company. Because a company can have brand and business model.

class CreateCompany(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:

        input = CompanyInput(description="These fields are required", required=True)

    class Meta:

        description = "Creates a new company"
        # model = models.Company

    errors = graphene.String()
    company = graphene.Field(CompanyNode)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, input=None):
        if not info.context.user.is_authenticated:
            return CreateCompany(errors=json.dumps('Please Login to list your company'))
        company = models.Company.objects.create(owner=info.context.user,
                                                name=input.name,
                                                email=input.email,
                                                )
        return CreateCompany(company=company, errors=None)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I hope this example will cover most of the topics as well for other people like me.

Comment: Are you trying to create different kinds of objects at the same time with a single mutation?  If that's the case, I would recommend an easier approach with two different mutations, where the id of the object returned from the first mutation is used as the foreign key id of the second mutation.

Comment: I am not sure on what's the best way to design an api. Wether to create a single mutation called CreateCompany(option 1) or have separate mutation like CreateCompany, CreateBrand and CreateBusinessModel.(option 2) Can you share this based on your experience, please? The way you are referring is i think somewhat same as second option.

Comment: "where the id of the object returned from the first mutation is used as the foreign key id of the second mutation". Does that mean, when i create a company object, i will have the id created as well which is PK of company. I then get that id and create a brand object and assign it to that newly created company object. Did i understand you clearly? Can you otherwise show just pseudo code on your approach, please? This can be i think the best reference a newbie can take like me.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand clearly.  I think that I may have answered this question before -- I'll check.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788006/create-mutations-in-graphql-with-a-lot-of-use-cases/49802184#49802184 -- it will help you understand your question